# How to make while loop in c

Tags: c, while-loop

Am trying to make while loop in my C code

like this:

```
main()
{
char q ;
while( a == 'yes' )   
{
    /* my code */
    printf("enter no to exit or yes to continue");
    scanf("%s",q);
 } 
}
```

but when i input the char " q " .... the console is crashed

and stop working

what is my wrong in while loop ??

Comment: Additionally, `'yes'` is not a character it is a string, so you need a `char <some_name>[]` array type to hold it, or a char pointer.

Comment: oh man please back to your preferred C book. Back here when you have a real question

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, no `'yes'` is a (multibyte) character constant (an `int`). `"yes"` is a `char` array.

Comment: @DanielFischer Does C support multibyte characters?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes, in different forms. Classical, multibyte ASCII constants, `'abcd'`, typically, the `int` is filled with the four (or fewer) bytes of the ASCII values of the characters within the quotes in an implementation-dependent manner. Nowadays, also with multibyte-encodings, a la `L'ü'`. Section 6.4.4.4, Character constants in the standard (section number may have been different in previous standard versions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several errors:

1. String literals should be surrounded by double quotes: `"yes"`, not `'yes'`.
2. String literals can't be compared to character variables.
3. `scanf` expects an address of the variable: `scanf("%s", &q)`, not `scanf("%s", q)`.
4. Apparently, you need array variable (`char q[4]`), not character one (`char q`).
5. Variable `a` referenced in condition `while( a == 'yes')` isn't declared.
6. You won't get your message on the screen since it's being buffered until `'\n'` is printed.

So what you probably need is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INP_SIZE 3
int main() {
    char inp[INP_SIZE + 1] = { 0 };
    while (strcmp(inp, "yes")) {
        printf("enter yes to continue or whatever else to exit\n");
        scanf("%3s", inp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I thought about constructing a format string to avoid duplication of `3`, but my laziness won.

Comment: viriable-sized object may not be initialized

Comment: in here """ char inp[inp_size + 1] = { 0 }; """

Answer (score 6):

You can't compare a string with `a == 'yes'`. You need to use `strcmp` function.

You need something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char a[200];
    strcpy(a, "yes");
    while( !strcmp(a, "yes") )
    {
       /* my code */
       printf("enter no to exit or yes to continue");
       scanf("%s",a);
    } 
}
```

Comment: This will only exit when a is "yes", the opposite of the poster's apparent intent.

Comment: What happens if you enter `lasagne` ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

use  `scanf("%s",&q);` instead of `scanf("%s",q);`.

You are not passing the address of `'q'` variable in `scanf` function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of mistakes.
1. a char is only a single character - infact it is actually a number
2. you write 'yes' using single quotes. This gives a char type and you should only ever have a single character in single quotes. e.g. 'y'
3. in c strings are held as arrays of char and you can't just compare them like you can integets.

I havn't checked this but try something like:

```
main() {
char buf[255]; //Set up an array of chars to hold the string
buf[0] = '/0'; //set the first charactory in the array to a null charactor.
               //c strings are null terminated so this sets it to an empty string

while ( strcmp(buf,"yes")==0) { //we have to use the strcmp function to compare the array
                                //also yes in double quotes is a null terminated char array so
printf("enter no to exit or yes to continue:"); //looks better with a colon
scanf("%s",buf); //scan f function will fill the buffer with a null terminated array
printf("\n"); //a new line here is nice
}
}
```

That might work for you. I don't have a c compiler to hand so I can't test it.

}

};

Answer (score 1):

No Address of of q, try adding a & before q, and add a strcmp(a, "yes") to properly evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
class WhileLoopExample {
     public static void main(String args[]){
        int i=10;
        while(i>1){
          System.out.println(i);
          i--;
        }
     }
}
```